# How to resize WPF DataGrid to fit its content?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, datagrid

### The aim

I would like to set such size for the DataGrid (standard, from WPF) so all cells (text) would be fully visible. I have window with DockPanel, with DataGrid in it, so when I resize the window, all nested widgets (DockPanel and DataGrid) are resized accordingly.

**Example (edit-1)**

*Let's say you have window, 100 pixels wide and you have DataGrid with one column, which cell is "the quick brown fox..." (400 pixels wide). Thus the DataGrid should be resized to 400 pixels (probably more, because of padding) and the Window should be resized to 400 pixels too (also more, because of padding).*

I didn't find any standard method to do it (AFAIK WPF provides way to clip the content to desired width, my problem is exactly opposite), so I come up with such ugly workaround, which does not work too well.

### The workaround

1. iterate over DataGrid headers (assuming they are just strings) and compute width required for the text
2. iterate over DataGrid rows per each column (assuming they are TextBlock or TextBox) and compute the maximum width required for the text -- add horizontal paddings for TextBlock/TextBox and horizontal margins for DataGrid cell
3. sum all differences between DataGrid ActualWidth for columns and the maximum width computed in (2)
4. increase the window width by the difference computed in (3)

## THE PROBLEM

I did several tests, and in some cases the computed width is too big (this is minor problem), for some cases is too small. The problem starts at its core procedure -- computing the required width for TextBox/TextBlock, computed width is always 1 unit less than it should be (if I set the width to computed one, 1 pixel from text is always clipped).

So **which factor I am ignoring here?** Or maybe better -- **is there already some method to resize DataGrid to fit its content?**

### The code

Computing width required for text (here for TextBlock):

```
    public static double TextWidth(this TextBlock widget, string text)
    {
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(text, // can use arbitrary text
                                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                              widget.FlowDirection,
                                              widget.FontFamily.GetTypefaces().FirstOrDefault(),
                                              widget.FontSize, 
                                              widget.Foreground);

        return formattedText.Width+widget.Padding.Left+widget.Padding.Right;
    }
```

Adjusting the Window size to fit DataGrid content (ugly_factor is ugly workaround ;-) since I didn't figure out how to fix it properly I set it to 1.3 and this way my window is "never" too small):

```
    public static void AdjustWidthToDataGrid(this Window window, DataGrid dataGrid, double ugly_factor)
    {
        var max_widths = dataGrid.Columns.Select(it => window.TextWidth(it.Header as string) 
                                                                        * ugly_factor).ToArray();

        foreach (var row in Enumerable.Range(0, dataGrid.Items.Count))
            foreach (var col in Enumerable.Range(0, dataGrid.Columns.Count))
            {
                var cell = dataGrid.GetCell(row, col);
                double width = 0;
                if (cell.Content is TextBlock)
                    width = (cell.Content as TextBlock).TextWidth();
                else if (cell.Content is TextBox)
                    width = (cell.Content as TextBox).TextWidth();

                if (cell.Content is FrameworkElement)
                {
                    var widget = cell.Content as FrameworkElement;
                    width = width + widget.Margin.Left + widget.Margin.Right;
                }

                max_widths[col] = Math.Max(max_widths[col], 
                                           width*ugly_factor+cell.Padding.Left+cell.Padding.Right);
            }

        double width_diff = 0;

        foreach (var col in Enumerable.Range(0, dataGrid.Columns.Count))
            width_diff += Math.Max(0,max_widths[col] - dataGrid.Columns[col].ActualWidth);

        if (width_diff > 0)
            window.Width = window.ActualWidth+ width_diff;
    }
```

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss with your resizing logic.
First of all, if you set the window's SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight", then the window is shown to the full size of the datagrid.
On the other hand, if you show a window at some predefined size, and you want to resize the window once the window is shown, then at that point resizing to the datagrid's desired with is very counter intuitive. Because the resizing will jump from say 100px to 400px, but what if I want to resize to only 250px... (asuming you resize by dragging the corner of the window)

Comment: Oh man, I spent entire week writing & checking my code which does the same as SizeToContent but in terrible way, and now I get to know there is an option for it? ;-) Life is ironic... Marko, you saved me. Please repost your comment as answer, and I mark it as THE answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Marko's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577944/how-to-resize-wpf-datagrid-to-fit-its-content#comment5107298_4577944) is the answer:

> I'm at a bit of a loss with your resizing logic. First of all, if you set the window's `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, then the window is shown to the full size of the datagrid. On the other hand, if you show a window at some predefined size, and you want to resize the window once the window is shown, then at that point resizing to the datagrid's desired with is very counter intuitive. Because the resizing will jump from say 100px to 400px, but what if I want to resize to only 250px... (asuming you resize by dragging the corner of the window)

Answer (score 26):

I just came out of the same problem where I had to give options in a data grid's column to fit its width as per the content of both header and cell. I used the following code:

```
private void FitToContent()
    {
        // where dg is my data grid's name...
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dg.Columns)
        {
            //if you want to size your column as per the cell content
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.SizeToCells);
            //if you want to size your column as per the column header
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.SizeToHeader);
            //if you want to size your column as per both header and cell content
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
        }
    }
```

Also I provided an option on columns to fit as per the display (datagrid's width). for that I used the same code above with the following minor change:

`column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);`

*FOR ALL COLUMNS* : Make sure you keep `HorizontalScrollVisibility` to `Auto`.

Comment: Note that these properties can also be applied via xaml, e.g. `<DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToHeader" ... />`

Comment: You should note also in your answer that "Auto" is the default for width, so people don't go needlessly littering their code with it. ;)

Answer (score 10):

If I understood your question right and you want to:

1. A DataGrid where columns are as wide as it's widest content.
2. The DataGrid fits to its contents.

This can be achieved with databinding:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          Height="111"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Margin="72,203,0,0"
          Name="dataGrid"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=grid}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Something1}"
                            Header="Column1" 
                            Width="Auto"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Something2}"
                            Header="Column2"
                            Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here the first column is as wide is needed and the second is spreaded space which is left. However the DataGrid's width is the same as Grid's widht that is around it, so the wanted outcome is achieved.

Comment: (1) yes, (2) yes, but I think you misunderstand (2) -- the content is what is within, not outside. Your XAML code sets the width of the DataGrid as big as the Grid OUTSIDE the DataGrid, when it should be vice-versa, setting the Grid (and Window) size as big as the DataGrid needs.

Comment: `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`  is made my grid to fit to content, earlier blank space after the last of coulmn of the grid was there... now solved

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I found DataGrid use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`  in default, So I set it to

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Then works.

Answer (score 1):

SizeToCells is what worked for me. I like this because its in XAML and it's concise.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToCells"/>
```

Comment: The value `SizeToCell` is not valid for me for `width` property on `DataGridTextColumn`, in WPF. Which framework do you use?

Comment: I think you cut off the end of the code snippet Width="SizeToCells". See the DataGridLengthUnitType Enum help. You should have it above 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

AutoGenarateColumns="False"